# How to get spotify Player in Android

Tags: android, spotify, spotify-app

On Successful Authorization, I am able to play hard coded track, but their is neither any player nor any pause, stop, play buttons there.

I followed [this](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/) tutorial, and did everything mentioned there.

Now i need to add spotify Player, but i am unable to find out any documentation related to this. I think i need to create the player layout myself, as player sdk provides different buttons callback, but there is nothing like using a predefined layout for player.

This is what i do after successful authorization.

```
        Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new SpotifyPlayer.InitializationObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onInitialized(SpotifyPlayer spotifyPlayer) {
                    mPlayer = spotifyPlayer;
                    mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(MainActivity.this);
                    mPlayer.addNotificationCallback(MainActivity.this);
                }


@Override
public void onLoggedIn() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "User logged in");

    mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V", 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you followed that tutorial, which you say you have and it seems to be working if you're able to play a track, then you have a `SpotifyPlayer` reference. That `getPlayer` method gives you that.

The `SpotifyPlayer` isn't a UI component though. Once you have that player (https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/player/) you would create your own UI, and wire up your buttons and such to the player actions (methods) and events.

Here is an example that might help (not complete or perfect!, not comprehensive, but a quick example from one sample project that might help to get started):

```
public class PlayerActivity extends BaseActivity  {

private ImageView buttonPlayPause;
private TextView labelNowPlaying;

private RecyclerView trackListRecyclerView;
private TrackListAdapter trackListAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager trackListLayoutManager;

private Player spotifyPlayer;
private ConnectionStateCallback spotifyConnectionStateCallback;
private Player.NotificationCallback spotifyPlayerNotificationCallback;
private Player.OperationCallback spotifyPlayerOperationCallback;
private String spotifyAccessToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    buttonPlayPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_play_pause);
    labelNowPlaying = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_now_playing);

    buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // toggle spot pause/play
            if (spotifyPlayer == null) {
                Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "Spotify player not ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // SpotifyPlayer provides init and connect methods; direct controls (play uri, pause, seek, skip, resume); and state (metadata and playbackstate)
                PlaybackState playbackState = spotifyPlayer.getPlaybackState();
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "playPause click, playbackState:" + playbackState);
                Metadata metadata = spotifyPlayer.getMetadata();

                if (!playbackState.isPlaying && playbackState.positionMs == 0) {
                    // nothing has been started yet play track 1
                    Track track = trackListAdapter.getFirstTrack();
                    labelNowPlaying.setText(track.getName());
                    spotifyPlayer.playUri(null, track.getUri(), 0, 0);
                    return;
                }

                if (playbackState.isPlaying) {
                    spotifyPlayer.pause(spotifyPlayerOperationCallback);
                    return;
                } 

                if (!playbackState.isPlaying && playbackState.positionMs > 0) {
                    // TODO how to tell if player is paused, idPlaying false and just position != 0? or is there an actual pause state, weird?
                    spotifyPlayer.resume(spotifyPlayerOperationCallback);
                    return;
                } 

                // get here it's weird
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "error unexepected playback state:" + playbackState);
                Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "Spotify playback state weird:" + playbackState, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    
            }
        }
    });

    spotifyPlayerNotificationCallback = new Player.NotificationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaybackEvent(PlayerEvent playerEvent) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify player notif callback: playback event: " + playerEvent.name());
            handleSpotifyEvent(playerEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackError(Error error) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify player notif callback: playback error: " + error.name());
            handleSpotifyError(error);
        }
    };

    // recycler view
    List<Track> playList = application.getPlaylist();
    trackListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.track_list_recycler);
    trackListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    trackListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    trackListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(trackListLayoutManager);
    trackListAdapter = new TrackListAdapter(PlayerActivity.this, playList);
    trackListRecyclerView.setAdapter(trackListAdapter);

    // get track list click events as observable
    trackListAdapter.asObservable().subscribe(new Action1<Track>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Track track) {
            // TODO make other adapter list items not clickable until one is processed?
            labelNowPlaying.setText(track.getName());
            spotifyPlayer.playUri(null, track.getUri(), 0, 0);
        }
    });

    // spotify player callback
    spotifyConnectionStateCallback = new ConnectionStateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLoggedIn() {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify connection callback: User logged in");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggedOut() {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify connection callback: user logged out");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginFailed(Error e) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify connection callback: login failed: " + e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTemporaryError() {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify connection callback: temp error occurred");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionMessage(String message) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify connection callback: connection message: " + message);
        }
    };

    spotifyPlayerOperationCallback = new Player.OperationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify operation callback: success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Error error) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify operation callback: error " + error.name());
            Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "Spotify op error: " + error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    spotifyAccessToken = application.getSpotifyAccessToken();
    initSpotifyPlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Spotify.destroyPlayer(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

//
// private
//

//
// SPOT
//

private void initSpotifyPlayer() {

    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "initSpotifyPlayer");

    if (spotifyAccessToken == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Spotify access token not present, cannot continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    Config playerConfig = new Config(this, spotifyAccessToken, application.getSpotifyClientId());
    Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new SpotifyPlayer.InitializationObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized(SpotifyPlayer player) {
            spotifyPlayer = player;
            spotifyPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(spotifyConnectionStateCallback);
            spotifyPlayer.addNotificationCallback(spotifyPlayerNotificationCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private void handleSpotifyEvent(final PlayerEvent playerEvent) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Spotify playerEvent:" + playerEvent.name());

    switch (playerEvent) {

        case kSpPlaybackEventAudioFlush:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyAudioDeliveryDone:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyBecameActive:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyBecameInactive:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyContextChanged:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyLostPermission:
            Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "Spotify player perms lost (logged in elsewhere?)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
            startActivity(new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyNext:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyPause:
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);                
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyPlay:
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
            // TODO get current playing track here? 
            //labelNowPlaying.setText(spotifyPlayer.getMetadata().currentTrack.
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyPrev:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyRepeatOff:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyRepeatOn:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyShuffleOff:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyShuffleOn:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackChanged:
            break;
        case kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackDelivered:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void handleSpotifyError(final Error error) {
    Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Spotify Error:" + error.name());

    switch (error) {
        // corrupt track, add is playing, need perms, travel restriction, etc
        default:
            break;
    }
}

}
```